# Deletion Operations in Dynamic Arrays

Tags: arrays, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

Edit: This is a continuation/extension of my previous post, which can be found here: [Dynamic array add at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705931/dynamic-array-add-at-the-end)

> Starting with a dynamic array `[5, 9, -1, 6, 4, 13, X, X]` of `length = 8` an `numElements = 6`, show the array when we carry out (a) 3 delete last operations and (b) 4 delete last operations. X denotes the entries, which can be ignored.

The checkpoint (answer) I got was (a) `[5, 9, -1, X, X, X, X, X]` and (b) `[5, 9, X, X]`.

Now the first one is fine with me.

```
[5, 9, -1, 6, 4, 13, X, X]
[5, 9, -1, 6, 4, X, X, X]
[5, 9, -1, 6, X, X, X, X]
[5, 9, -1, X, X, X, X, X]
```

So this was I should get the answer of (a).

What about (b) though? Here is my try:

```
[5, 9, -1, X, X, X, X, X]
[5, 9, X, X, X, X, X, X]
```

From here, since the length is 8 and it is equal to 4 * number elements (which is 4 * 2 = 8), so I will cut the array by half, reducing the length is 4.

```
[5, 9, X, X]
```

But why does it stop here/why `[5, 9, X, X]` was the final answer? That was only 2 deletions operations and we have 4 in total, what happens next?

Here is the pseudo-code of I'm trying to do:

```
function deleteLast()
if (numElements == 0) then
print “Cannot delete from an empty array”
else if (numElements == 1) then
set numElements to 0
set length to 1
resize array A to 1
else
decrement numElements
if (4 ∗ numElements == length) then
update length to 2 ∗ numElements
create an array B of size length
use a loop to copy first numElements numbers from A to B
set A to B
```

Comment: I'm trying to do deleteLast() operation.

Comment: Using what, what's the implementation of this stuff? Java arrays do not have a `deleteLast()` method.

Comment: What is a "delete last" operation? How does this relate to Java? Is there code behind this question or is this all conceptual stuff?

Comment: Growing / shrinking the allocated space is expensive, so I doubt that java dynamic arrays (aka ArrayList) call shrink in that situation.  But you could delve the code for ArrayList, it's open source.

Comment: ArrayList implementation is here, I don't see where they ever shrink the capacity, except in a publicly exposed method called trimToSize().  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

Comment: Sorry folks I realized what you meant. I misplaced the java tag. This is actually data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just asked my instructor. He said that the delete operation for part b also starts from the initial stack `[5, 9, -1, 6, 4, 13, X, X]`. The same step applies for part b - and when we get to 2 elements, we cut the length to half, as per the pseudo-code I attached.